# Pandas to_datetime produces inconsistent dates

Tags: python, pandas

to_datetime seems to produce different base dates (pandas-0.12.0)

```
pd.to_datetime('03:00:00.017158433')
Timestamp('2013-10-22 03:00:00.017158', tz=None)

pd.to_datetime(10800017158433, unit='ns')
Timestamp('1970-01-01 03:00:00.017158433', tz=None)
```

Is this a bug? Or is it an issue with usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It IS correct, but its in nano-seconds from epoch, (e.g. 19700101 00:00:00)

```
In [3]: pd.to_datetime('03:00:00.017158433')
Out[3]: Timestamp('2013-10-22 03:00:00.017158', tz=None)

In [4]: pd.to_datetime('03:00:00.017158433').value
Out[4]: 1382410800017158000

In [5]: pd.to_datetime(1382410800017158000,unit='ns')
Out[5]: Timestamp('2013-10-22 03:00:00.017158', tz=None)
```

where is *10800017158433* from

its not a valid epoch time stamp (well it is, but its probably not what you want)

You stated that this is from midnight, so you can do this.

```
In [2]: Timestamp(Timestamp('20131022').value+10800017158433)
Out[2]: Timestamp('2013-10-22 03:00:00.017158433', tz=None)
```

Comment: The ns timestamp being provided is from midnight. Its surprising (possibly incorrect) that only one of them is treated to be from epoch

Comment: thats a non-standard usage; and its not even a datetime, more like a timedelta, is that what you want? there is a ``to_timedelta`` coming in 0.13 that would handle that; I updated.

Comment: In this particular case, its all intraday data with no 'date' information. It doesn't matter what date gets appended as long as its consistent across input datatypes to allow comparison. Or maybe there is a different way to work with such data?

Comment: what are you going to do with it? As I show above you can convert to a datelike if you want (or not), or make it a timedelta if you want as well

Comment: Why should it need either change? The workflow would be just fine if to_datetime treated time only strings like '03:00:00.xxx' to be time from start of epoch. Its counter intuitive for it to append today's date to it

Comment: ``to_datetime`` DOES NOT append today's date, nor does it assume anything. I gave you an example which does exactly what you want. A time-only string is supported as a timedelta, as I stated above.

Comment: My bad, I used the term append loosely. However to_datetime does assume a date that I did not provide in case of string input. My point is simply that the following MUST be true -
pd.to_datetime('03:00:00.017158433').value == pd.to_datetime(10800017158433, unit='ns')

Comment: sorry..it does assume a time has today's date; otherwise would break lots of things, this is the default for dateutil as well. You are free to do it like this if you want:  ``pd.to_datetime('19700101 03:00:00.017158433').value``